# How to call method which is placed in class stored in array of objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have class Jorney where you have several variables and some methods that returns those variables values.

```
    public class Jorney {





   private int timeH;


   public Jorney(int timeH)
            {
                this.timeH=timeH;
             }
   private int getTimeH()
         {
       return townFrom;
         }
}
```

and than i have another class where i create ArrayList of objects

```
ArrayList<Object> myJorney = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

now when I add some objects to ArrayList my aim is to go through all those 'jorneys'(objects) call getTimeH() method and store its parameters in variables.

I use iterator to go from one object to another but dunno how to call the method.

```
private int totalTime()
 {

     Iterator<Object> i = myJorney.iterator();
     int sum;

     while (i.hasNext()) {
       Object j = i.next();
       int hour= j.getTimeH();
       sum=sum+hour;
        }
     return sum;
```

I am wondering if someone could help me with that?

Comment: You need to cast the object from the iterator to the type of your class, but be careful!

Comment: Better yet use `Jorney` as your generic type instead of `Object`.

Comment: If there's other objects in there, and you only want to do something for the `Jorney` ones, then I suggest you rethink your design.

Comment: Why do you have a `List<Object>` instead of `List<Journey>`?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to store your `Journey` objects in an array of `Object`s, you need a cast:

```
Journey j = (Journey)i.next();
```

However, you would be better off declaring your list with `Journey` as its type parameters:

```
ArrayList<Journey> myJorney = new ArrayList<Journey>();
```

In this case, you would be able to use `Iterator<Journey>`, and make the call without a cast:

```
Jorney j = i.next()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your object back to `Jorney` before calling the `Jorney` class methods. Try this:

```
   int hour= ((Jorney)j).getTimeH();
```

You need to cast it because otherwise you will be calling method on `Object` class instance. And `Object` class does not have any method with name `getTimeH()`

Answer (score 0):

Cast to `Jorney`  your object geting from `iterator`

```
 while (i.hasNext()) {
   Jorney j =(Jorney) i.next();
   int hour= j.getTimeH();
   sum=sum+hour;
    }
```